# Simple C app using 50% cpu

Tags: c

I have a simple C app that uses constant 50%. I don't know why but I like to minimize it as much as possible.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void Wait(int seconds)
{
clock_t endwait;
endwait = clock () + seconds * CLK_TCK ;
while (clock() < endwait) {}
}

void main()
{
printf ("program running.\n");
/* Wait( 4 ); */
printf( "Done Waiting!\n" );
printwow();
/* exit(0); */
}

timer_func (void)
{
Wait( 4 );
printwow();
}

printwow()
{
printf ("Say hello");
timer_func();
}
```

I guess it must be the timer of course. But I don't know that for sure.

Thanks.

Comment: that's an infinite loop (timer_func always call  printwow and vice-versa) and you probably have a dual core pc, so the running thread it's occupying 100% of one of the cpus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some built-in sleep function, that does not use processor cycles to "wait", like `sleep` from `unistd.h`.

Answer (score 21):

Your loop:

```
while (clock() < endwait) {}
```

is [busy-waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). You are basically having the following conversation with the CPU.

"Are we there yet?"  "No."

"Are we there yet?"  "No."

"Are we there yet?"  "No."

(repeat several gazillion times)

"Are we there yet?"  "Yes."

You are better off using a function like `sleep()` which tells the CPU to tell you when it's ready.

Comment: use sleep, or select. to wait for things like this.

Comment: Just to add Google Keywords: busy-waiting is also called a Spinlock.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone. I will test it out immediately. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's your tight loop in `Wait()`. You probably have a dual-core machine, so you're using 100% of one core. Use `sleep()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`timer_func()` and `printwow()` call each other forever. You'll eventually get a stack overflow.

Comment: Hah, I saw that and totally missed the spinlock.

Answer (score 1):

because the loop

```
while (clock() < endwait) {}
```

cpu has to check the value of clock() all the time, use sleep() instead of your own code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to sleep for 4 seconds then you can use sleep(4) to do that and it will almost certainly not consume CPU like your wait() function does.  Note that sleep(4) will block execution of the remainder of your single-threaded program and if you do not want that then you will need something more sophisticated, but I suspect sleep(4) will suffice here.

Also, your code will eventually exhaust the stack because printwow() calls timer_func() which calls printwow() which calls timer_func() etc. etc. ad infinitum in a recursive loop.  You need to fix this, probably by using a for/while loop rather than recursion.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I fix it with an infinite while loop. while(1){Sleep(4000); printwow();}. And yes I would be interested in a non-blocking timer. Though I must say I am not a C coder. :)