# C Time Delay Hogs CPU

Tags: c, time, delay, cpu

I tried to write a CUI Snake game using the ncurses library and C. Everything's working fine, but when I run the program the CPU usage shoots to 50% (from 8ish or lower initially)

After commenting out various parts of the code, I identified the main culprit to be the time delay function I used, which ensures that a new frame is drawn every 90ms. (I obtained the function's source from a website)

```
void waitFrom(clock_t init, long pauseclocks)
{
    while((clock() - init) < pauseclocks);
}
```

and in the main function:

```
clock_t start;
long pause = 90 * (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
while(1)
{
    start = clock();
    //game code
    waitFrom(start, pause);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Busy looping uses CPU, that's how it works.

Comment: What did you expect?   Even just calling `sched_yield` inside the loop would improve this.

Comment: Perhaps it would better to write your code to act on events driven by a timer. Otherwise, perhaps using [nanosleep](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) would reduce CPU usage.

Comment: See [Simple C app using 50% cpu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7677219).

Comment: nanosleep was what i needed. Thank you

Comment: @kkaranth You are encouraged to post an answer to you question and contribute back to this site, which helped you find the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : Why did you post that as a comment when it is clearly an answer?

Comment: @self. Since this is my first post on stackoverflow i wasn't permitted to answer my own question

Comment: The question cited as a duplicate required delays in seconds and the answers all suggest `sleep()` - that is not an appropriate solution in this case.  I would suggest that this question therefore has merit on its own and might be reopened.

Comment: @Clifford Because they were just suggestions as I know nothing concrete about C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay would consume 100% of a single core - presumably you have a dual-core processor?

Replace your delay with:

```
usleep( 90000 ) ;  // 90ms
```

You need to `#include <unistd.h>` for [`usleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).

This will *suspend the thread* for 90ms rather than *busy wait*.